# Start running a .exe file before quitting a python program without a console window popping up after the python program quits

Tags: python, automation, github-api

## This is a problem about .exe program starting with Python

Recently I've been working on the auto-update function for my github program.

The effect I want is that, after running the following function, if there's a newer version, the current program must shut down completely before the launching of the new installer downloaded.

**The installer must be silently started, and install the new program normally.**

Previously I found that as long as the python program was killed, the installer.exe was always shut down together, with whatever method to start the installer.

But later on I discovered, that problem would disappear when I have the program packaged with pyinstaller, and run the packaged .exe file, but that's still not perfect due to the following issue:

***The thing is, A cmd console would pop up as long as the original program ends***

Here are the relevant codes:

```
def update_checker(ask_update=False):
    has_newer = is_mf_need_update()
    if has_newer and tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(
            title='...', message='need update?'):
        root.withdraw()
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(
            title='...', message='update_downloading')
        new_exe_name = has_new_installer_downloaded()  # returns the name of the newly downloaded installer.exe
        if not new_exe_name:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror(
                title='...', message='update_download_failed')
            return  # Do not exit
        # Problem's here
        os.system(f'"{os.path.join(DOWNLOAD_TEMP_PATH, new_exe_name)}"')
        exit_program()  # destroy the tkinter root, and so on
    elif not has_newer and ask_update:  # Proactively update
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(
               title='...', message='update_no_newer')
```

- Here's the current effect:
  Ask if update's needed: [image: Ask if update's needed]

Donwloading new installer:
[image: Donwloading new installer]

Here the cmd root pops up after the previous process end and the installer starts
[image: Here the cmd root pops up]

I know there's a solution like, starting another program to start the installer, but such program would take up more space, and more importantly, the whole program previously running would be rewritten completely after the installation. So that wouldn't work, as I think.

and I tried 'start \B [installer_route]' command, but that doesn't work somehow, maybe that's another way?

ps: The cmd window won't appear if the previous program doesn't quit, but I have to kill the previous one

**Is there a nice solution for that? I mean, just let the cmd window disappear, and that's prefect for now**

Comment: I would suggest you replace the `os.system` call with `subprocess.Popen`, and use the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag to prevent a CMD window from appearing.

Comment: Do what @Obaskly said but also add the `DETACHED_PROCESS`  and `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` flags otherwise the process will end when the parent (the script) is stopped/killed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use subprocess

```
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, DETACHED_PROCESS, CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP

'''
Replace
os.system(f'"{os.path.join(DOWNLOAD_TEMP_PATH, new_exe_name)}"')
With the Followings:
'''
Popen([new_exe_name], shell=True,
                  creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW | DETACHED_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
```

Then the installer would continue running normally after the shutting down the previous program

**That works perfectly**

***Thanks for @Obaskly and @DerSchinken's Help!***